# Text binding with Pane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, text, dynamic, bind

```
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.text.*;

public class PieChart extends Application{
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final double WIDTH = 600;
    final double HEIGHT = 600;
    Pane pane = new Pane();
    pane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightBlue");
    Arc arc1 = new Arc(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 200, 200, 0, 72);
    arc1.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
    arc1.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
    arc1.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc1.setFill(Color.RED);
    Text text1 = new Text(375, 250, "Project -- 20%");

    Arc arc2 = new Arc(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 200, 200, 72, 36);
    arc2.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
    arc2.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
    arc2.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
    Text text2 = new Text(270, 95, "Quiz -- 10%");

    Arc arc3 = new Arc(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 200, 200, 108, 108);
    Text text3 = new Text(150, 250, "Midterm -- 30%");
    arc3.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
    arc3.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
    arc3.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc3.setFill(Color.GREEN);

    Arc arc4 = new Arc(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, 200, 200, 216, 144);
    Text text4 = new Text(300, 400, "Final -- 40%");
    arc4.centerXProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().divide(2));
    arc4.centerYProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().divide(2));
    arc4.setType(ArcType.ROUND);
    arc4.setFill(Color.ORANGE);
    pane.getChildren().addAll(arc1, arc2, arc3, arc4, text1, text2, text3, text4);

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Pie Chart");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}
}
```

[Link to what my program looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tj1ds.png)

Hello everyone, I have a program that creates a pi chart using multiple arcs and text. I binded the centerX and centerY property values to half the width and height of my pane to make it so the pi chart stays in the center even when you readjust the window. However I tried binding my text to the pane the same way and nothing would show. As of right now, I just manually put in x and y values to put my text in the correct place, however if i readjust the window, the piChart stays in the center but the text does not. How can I edit my text to make it more dynamic where it looks like the picture in the link but stays that way even when I change the size of the window?

Comment: You know there is already a PieChart class you can use to represent data in a Pie Chart right? https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/charts/pie-chart.htm

Comment: Yes, but this was just a specific example to help me understand binding in javaFx.

Comment: In that case, you will need to find the location of each Text ( some maths here ) and then bind the text.layoutXProperty() & text.layoutYProperty().